# jQuery: get all elements with text as it's immediate children, including descendants?

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to grab all elements containing text.

```
$(*).each(function(){
    if ($(this).nodeType == 3) return $(this).parent();
}).get();
```

however when there's an element like

```
<div>somewhere <span class='special'> here <b>now</b></span></div>
```

However using my code it will return `<div>somewhere </div>` and `<span>here</span>` and `<b>now</b>` separately. I would like for it to return `<div>somewhere here now</div>`.

If an element only has text contents, then this is fine

```
<div>only this</div>
```

should give me `<div>only this</div>` as it has no descendants.

What I'm wary about is big containers getting returned like:

```
<div>

<a>some</a>

<b>where</b>

</div>
```

that should give me `<a>some</a>` and `<b>where</b>, and not the whole`div` because there is many whitespaces in between.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function get(ct) {
    return $(ct).find('*').filter(function () {
        return $(this).contents().filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) != '';
        }).length != 0
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CghyL/)